domain migration to different host
I have domain.org on host-it servers with plesk control panel with multiple inboxes and each inbox has multiple aliases.
The mailboxes contain a lot of mail in the inbox/sent folder and multiple subfolders.
I want to move to better-host who also use plesk.
Is there a way to take a dump of the email configuration from host-it and import it to better-host?
Can I also export the emails from host-it and import to better-host?
Don't much care about the web site contents
web searching has not revealed much
